# Oracle SQL query - get data from last week (Monday-Saturday)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a query that would show data added in last week (always beginning with Monday), from ***COLUMNNAME***, ***TABLENAME***. I also have a column with dates, ***adddate***.
It seems not to work... How would I fix it?

```
select COLUMNNAME
from TABLENAME 

where adddate >= (TRUNC(adddate - 7 - (TRUNC (adddate)- TRUNC (adddedate, 'IW'))))
and adddate < (TRUNC(adddate - 7 - (TRUNC (adddate)- TRUNC (adddedate, 'IW'))))+6
```

Comment: This works for me:        SELECT
TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7 - (TRUNC (SYSDATE)- TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'IW'))),
TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7 - (TRUNC (SYSDATE)- TRUNC (SYSDATE+6, 'IW')))
FROM DUAL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your expression needs the current date in it somewhere, such as:

```
where adddate >= next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 14 and
      adddate < next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 7
```

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . Yes I did.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a note, argument of `NEXT_DAY` depends on local NLS-Settings. Ensure that your current session use "English" as `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`